# Proof that $\mathrm{Var}\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nY_i\bigg) = \frac{1}{n}\mathrm{Var}(Y_1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, variance

Let $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a set of $n$ i.i.d. random variables $Y_i$.

I am trying to prove:

$$\mathrm{Var}\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nY_i\bigg) = \frac{1}{n}\mathrm{Var}(Y_1)$$

My work:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}\bigg[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nY_i\bigg] &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\bigg[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(Y_i-\bar Y_n\bigg)\bigg]^2\\\\
&=\tfrac{1}{n} \cdot n \cdot \bigg[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\big(Y_i-\bar Y_n\big)\bigg]^2\\\\
&=\bigg[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(Y_i-\bar Y_n\bigg)\bigg]^2\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n\big(Y_i-\bar Y_n\big)\bigg]^2 \\\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
$$

I know my conclusion is false but I am wondering where my mistake is. Thank you.

Comment: Why there is a summation over $j$ at the very first equality?

Comment: Should it be i? I wasn`t sure which index I should use @Atbey

Comment: No, it is not about index. Why there is a summation?

Comment: that comes from the variance formula @atbey

Comment: $Var(X) = E((X-EX)^2)$?

Comment: @KaanYolsever Are you trying to show that the variance equals $\frac{1}{n} \mathrm{Var}(Y_1)$? Or should that $Y_1$ be $Y_i$?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have the index $j$; it should be $i$ for all your summations.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire because $Y_i$ is i.i.d $Y_i$ is the same for all i`s, namely 1. But that`s what the prof asked me to prove

Comment: Gotcha. So I think one problem with your proof is that there seems to be an implicit assumption that $Y_i = \bar Y_n$, because that's the only way you could say that the sum $\frac{1}{n}\big(\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar Y)\big)^2$ can equal $0$. However, this isn't always true. 

@atbey has provided a good answer using the definition of variance, which I think is the one you preferred. My answer uses one of the useful properties of the variance to make quick work of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\bar Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ denote the sample mean. Then

$$
\mathrm{Var}\bigg[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\bigg] = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}\big[Y_i\big]
$$

Since each $Y_i$ is i.i.d. it follows that for distinct $i$ and $j$ where $i,j \in \{1, 2, \dotsc, n\}$,

$$\mathrm{Var}\big[Y_i\big] = \mathrm{Var}\big[Y_j\big]$$

So now we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}\bigg[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\bigg] &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}\big[Y_i\big]\\\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n\mathrm{Var}\big[Y_i\big] \\\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \mathrm{Var}\big[Y_i\big]
\end{align*}
$$

Because $\mathrm{Var}\big[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\big] = \frac{1}{n} \mathrm{Var}[Y_i]$ is true for all $i = 1,2, \dotsc, n$, we choose $i=1$ to obtain

$$\mathrm{Var}\bigg[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\bigg] = \frac{1}{n} \mathrm{Var}[Y_1]$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand this but why do I get a non-sense conclusion when I expand the variance and try to solve it? @Benedict Voltaire

Comment: @KaanYolsever So your last equation in your post confuses me. Why were you able to deduce that the sum equals $0$?

Comment: isn`t the sum $X_i-\overline{X_n}$ zero?

Comment: @KaanYolsever Not necessarily. For example, here is a set of numbers $\{4,5,6\}$. Then $\overline X = \frac{15}{3} = 5$. Then if you let $X_1 = 4$ and $X_2 = 5$, then $X_2 - \overline X = 0$, but $X_1 - \overline X = -1$. 
Does that help?